# Is it possible to decapsulate ERSPAN and forward on RSPAN?

Tags: ids, cisco-nexus, nexus, alienvault

I am currently running into an issue where we are trying to send our network traffic from our physical infrastructure into a virtual Alienvualt appliance, but our switches are unable to send RSPAN traffic.

Nexus 9k's support SPAN and ERSPAN.
Alienvault supports SPAN and RSPAN.
SPAN is not an option as we have multiple hops between Alienvault and the switch.

Is it possible to capture that ERSPAN traffic on another host, demodulate, then continue forwarding on as RSPAN?

Are there any other creative options out there that could solve this puzzle?